# Video background on Desktop, Image on Mobile is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a website that has a video background on the desktop view (this is already inplace and functioning); but when loaded on a mobile device it displays an image.

```
 <div class="main">      
   <video autoplay muted loop> 
   <source src="Main-Stream.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   </video>
  <div class="content container">
    <h1>Discover the Lifetarian Way</h1>
    <a href="x" class="btn">Purchase the Book</a>
  </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, use media queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to set `display: none` to the `video` element. However, media queries are only useful to determine size of the page, so they can only serve as a **heuristic** to determine if data is actually costly.

If you want to do something different depending on the type of connection (mobile/wifi), you'd need something like the [navigator.connection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection) but that's far from being standard.